# Ошибка загрузки файлов Yii2

Tags: yii2

Делаю загрузку фото в редактировании профиля. Для поля загрузки поля прописал

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput(); ?>
```

Когда отправляю форму, делаю вывод того, что передается

```
print_r(Yii::$app->request->post());
```

и получаю это

```
Array ( [_csrf] => SzZPazVRNHUbRx80fSFXAAEBGz1mB1gNOG96HVwVWTBmQX8denx.Ig== [EditProfile] => Array ( [username] => zaych [email] => mail@site.ru [first_name] => Admin [second_name] => Admin [image] => ) [signup-button] => )
```

То есть, поле image пустое, хотя фото выбираю. Для формы прописал

```
'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
```

Так же делаю так

```
$file->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($file, 'image'); print_r($file->image);
```

И тоже пусто
В чем может быть ошибка?

Добавляю код:
1) Представление

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                        'id' => 'edit-profile',
                        'options' => ['class' => 'form-horizontal', 'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'],
                        'fieldConfig' => [
                            'options' => ['class' => 'input-group'],
                            'inputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control']
                        ],
                    ]);
                    ?>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'username')->textInput(['value'=>$info['username']]); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'email')->textInput(['value'=>$info['email']]); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'first_name')->textInput(['value'=>$info['first_name']]); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'second_name')->textInput(['value'=>$info['second_name']]); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?= $form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput(); ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <?= Html::submitButton('Зарегистрироваться', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'name' => 'signup-button']) ?>
                    </div>
```

2) Модель

```
namespace frontend\models\profile;

use yii\base\Model;
use yii\web\UploadedFile;

class UploadForm extends Model
{
/**
 * @var UploadedFile
 */
public $image;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['image'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, gif, bmp'],
    ];
}

public function upload()
{
    if ($this->validate()) {
        print_r($this->image);exit;
        $this->image->saveAs('/source/user/' . $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension);
        return $this->image->baseName . '.' . $this->image->extension;
    } else {
        return 'error';
    }
}
}
```

3) Контроллер

```
public function actionProfileEdit(){
    $user=new User();
    $model=new EditProfile();
    $file=new UploadForm();
    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
        $file->image = UploadedFile::getInstance($file, 'image');
        print_r($file->image);exit;
        $res=$file->upload();
        if ($model->updateProfile()){
            ?>
            <script>msg('Профиль успешно изменен', 'success');</script>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <script>msg('Произошла ошибка', 'error');</script>
            <?php
        }
    }

    $params = [
        'sid' => Yii::$app->user->identity->sid,
        'role' => $user->getUserType(),
        'info' => $user->getUserInfo(),
        'uid' => Yii::$app->user->getId(),
        'model' => $model
    ];
    return $this->render('profile/profile-edit', $params);
}
```

Comment: покажите действие контроллера, модель, представление

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Думаю понятно что в массиве `$_POST` (в данном случае метод который его возвращает `Yii::$app->request->post()`) файл вы не найдете. Файлы только в массиве `$_FILES`.

Yii добавляет помимо `input[type="file"]` еще и `input[type="hidden"]` с именем `image`, по этому вы видите в `post` пустое поле.

Вся проблема у вас в том что файл вы отправляете с именем адресованным модели `EditProfile`, а ищете его в модели `UploadForm`.

Метод `UploadedFile::getInstance()` запрашивает модель не просто так, он формирует из название класса модели имя и ищет в массиве `$_FILES`.

В итоге ваш код  `UploadedFile::getInstance($file, 'image')` ищет файл в `$_FILES[UploadForm][image]` а он у вас, из-за - `$form->field($model, 'image')->fileInput()`, приходит в `$_FILES[EditProfile][image]`.

Или передайте в представление экземпляр класса UploadForm и измените поле формы:

`$form->field($file, 'image')->fileInput()`

Или измените `UploadedFile::getInstance()` на `UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'image')`. Ничто не мешает перенести атрибут, правили, и метод загрузки в модель `EditProfile`, если нет цели делать уникальную модель для загрузки файлов.

Comment: спасибо огромное, вы очень помогли. я только разбираюсь с yii2, поэтому делаю такие ошибки. может вы можете посоветовать хорошу книгу по yii2?

Comment: Книг не знаю, их гайд в полне хорош - http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-index.html (есть перевод), и документация. Когда возникают проблемы,  стоит изучить исходный код, и все встает на места, плюс опыт.

Comment: спасибо за помощь